# MySQL Workbench reports SELECT is not valid at this position for this server version” error

Tags: mysql

For the following SQL query:

```
SELECT orders.Freight,

FORMAT(Freight,1) as 'Freight Format' ,
CONVERT(int, Freight) as 'Freight Convert' ,
CAST(Freight AS int) as 'Freight Cast'

FROM orders
```

I receive the following error message:

> "SELECT" is not valid at this position for this server version,
>   expecting: '(', WITH

I am a total newbie at SQL. How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your query.

1. In the syntax of CONVERT, the value should be the first argument and the type should be the second argument.
2. There is no 'int' type. You must use either SIGNED or UNSIGNED. (Use UNSIGNED if that field never has negative values)

Fixed query:

```
SELECT
    orders.Freight, 
    FORMAT(Freight,1) as 'Freight Format', 
    CAST(Freight AS SIGNED) as 'Freight Cast', 
    CONVERT(Freight, SIGNED) as 'Freight Convert' 
FROM orders
```

Simplified reference (W3Schools) for Convert and Cast functions:

- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp

Official MySQL Reference for cast functions:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: @YanbinLi Don't forget to upvote useful answers and mark them as useful if they solved your question.